# Cast a special java object to an integer

Tags: java, object, casting, integer

I've created a program, which helds the grades of the pupils. I've created a class Grade and now I am using it as an object. Now I want to calculate the average of the grades. Do you know any possible way to cast it to an Integer?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Seems like x-y question. Please take a tour - stackoverflow.com/tour and ask a specific question..

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html ?

Comment: If your `Grade` class has an integer field, you don't need to cast it, you need to retrieve the value from the field. If it doesn't, then what is the relationship between a `Grade` and an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have at least one attribute in your Grades class. 
You cant cast Grade to Integer. 
Calculate grades in your main/test or other class via get method.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to convert custom object(Grades in this case) to Integer and you can't. If Grades are just integers , you don't have to create the separate class for it. If it has more than one attribute and then the right attribute from grade class and do whatever processing you want.